# yq not modifying YAML file when used within Jenkins environment/job

Tags: docker, jenkins, yaml, yq

As part of an eventual automated pipeline, I need to modify a certain YAML file I have with a version that will be made available through the build parameters of a Jenkins job. The YAML file I need to modify looks something like the following:

```
apiVersion: v2
appVersion: '1.0'
dependencies:
- condition: name1.enabled
  name: name1
  version: 1.20.0-9
- condition: name2.enabled
  name: name2
  version: 1.20.0-9
- condition: name3.enabled
  name: name3
  version: 4.10.0+8
description: A Helm chart for blah-blah
name: chart-name
version: 1.20.0-10
```

Only `name3`'s version needs to modified. There is an docker image that is available to me that includes the `yq` package, which is a command-line YAML, JSON and XML processor.

Locally, a command like this works and does modify the file correctly:
`docker run --init --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --volume $PWD/chart/chart-name:$PWD <docker-image-with-yq>:latest yq-4.x eval "(.dependencies[] | select(.name == \"$matchName\")).version = \"$newVersion\"" $PWD/Chart.yaml -i` where "`matchName`" would be "`name3`" and "`newVersion`" is the new version to update to.

When I run this locally, I can see the file does get modified.

However, if I was to then include this command in my Jenkinsfile for the associated Jenkins job, I can see that when I `cat` the file after running the above, the file remains unchanged. I also see no error messages either.

What I expect to happen is that when the Jenkins job gets to the stage where it runs the above `docker run` command, the file should then be updated with the provided version.

Is there maybe some extra configuration needed for the docker run command to allow it modify the file? Is it possibly failing silently?